# Site left aligned in IE, fine in FF

Tags: css

http://www.christywhiteheadphotography.com/PIxelStixStudio/

My assumption is it is something to do with:

> .col-full  { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; }

not being used by IE, but I am really not sure.

Any help appreciated,

Thanks,
Ken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE doesn't automatically apply `overflow:hidden` if there isn't also a width/height set on the element. In your case the width of the slider is breaking the layout of the page. Try adding a width to the slides container like so:

```
.slides_container { width: 890px; }
```

Comment: Thanks Jasuten,That seemed to have fixed part of the issue, everything is still aligned left though :(

Comment: You also have issues in your html. There shouldn't be any code before <!DOCTYPE html> & you have javascript being loaded there.

Comment: forgot to mention this was a wordpress site.